# Can I improve my duplicate-detection queries?

Tags: query-performance, duplication, monetdb

I have a DB table with US domestic flight data which I am in the process of sorta-kinda-de-duplicating. The schema appears [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime-tools/master/other_queries/create_schema.sql), but it is probably not very important. There are no perfectly-duplicate records; rather, I have a several fields which almost form a unique key: year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin; and under 0.1% of the records share the same values on these fields with other records.

What I want to do is isolate these "pseudo-duplicates" or key-violators, i.e. pairs of records which have the same values on these columns.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dupe_keys AS (
    SELECT year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin 
    FROM (
        SELECT count(*) AS cnt, year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin 
        FROM ontime
        GROUP BY year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin
    ) AS t WHERE cnt > 1
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

This query takes quite a lot of time (relative to an ideal possible implementation outside of a DBMS based on sorting the key columns). I then run:

```
CREATE TABLE dupes AS (
    SELECT  o.year_,o.quarter,o.month_,o.dayofmonth,o.dayofweek,o.flightdate,o.uniquecarrier,o.airlineid,o.carrier,o.tailnum,bunch_of,other_fields,go_here 
    FROM ontime AS o, dupe_keys AS dk
    WHERE 
            o.year_         = dk.year_ 
        AND o.month_        = dk.month_ 
        AND o.dayofmonth    = dk.dayofmonth 
        AND o.uniquecarrier = dk.uniquecarrier 
        AND o.flightnum     = dk.flightnum 
        AND o.origin        = dk.origin 
    ORDER BY o.year_ ASC, o.month_ ASC, o.dayofmonth ASC, o.uniquecarrier ASC, o.flightnum ASC, o.origin ASC
);
```

which obviously takes less time.

I would like to achieve the same, faster, with better queries. Alternatively, I wouldn't mind something like a pair of tables of the same size, each with one of the two dupes out of a dupe set.

Notes:

- You may assume that no combination of key-column values appears *more* than twice. It's either once or twice.
- I'm using MonetDB, a columnar in-memory DBMS. hence the syntax specifics.
- I hope my question is not DBMS-specific, but in case it is - answers based on the behavior of other DBMSes are still relevant, just please state which DBMS you're assuming.
- This query is run when the data set is loaded, rather than repeatedly, So pre-computation which takes even more time is not relevant.

Comment: have a combined index on year, o.month, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier,flightnum, origin

Comment: @nbk: 1. Wouldn't that take more time than this query? 2. Note that MonetDB indices [are somewhat different](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/TableDefinitions/IndexDefinitions).

Comment: it is a commenta dn the documentation states that it uses those indices, manually made indeces are used to helpo the rdms when it automamtion has to be improved, also mostl times you can force also an index

Comment: Does `MonetDB` support `row_number` because then this because much easier, it can be done in a single query

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, it does support row_number as a window function, see [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLReference/FunctionsAndOperators/WindowFunctions).

Answer (score 1):

This will either require a hash or a sort to group records having the same key. Hash can only be done in memory, but sorting can use external storage. If you have a lot of data, it will probably use a merge disk sort.

So the first thing to do would be to look what it is using, and if it is a sort, then look into memory configuration options to allocate more working memory to reduce the number of passes (this would be work_mem in postgres).

Second would be to partition the table by some key, like year or year,month. Then run the duplicate search on each partition instead of the whole table. Ideally you'd want the partitions to be small enough that the slow disk merge sort can be replaced by an in-memory hash or quicksort.

EDIT: I tried it on clickhouse. With compression enabled, the database is about the same size as the zipped csv files.

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt, Year, Month, DayofMonth, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, Origin 
FROM ontimec
WHERE Year=2001
GROUP BY Year, Month, DayofMonth, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, Origin 
HAVING cnt>1;
```

This takes about 0.5 seconds and returns 1349948 rows, out of the 5967780 rows that have Year=2001. Are you sure about "only 0.1% of rows are duplicates?"...

Window functions have to be [enabled](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/), then:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, count(*) over (partition by Year, Month, DayofMonth, UniqueCarrier, FlightNum, Origin) cnt
    FROM ontimec
    WHERE Year=2001) foo
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

This also works, it takes 1.5s, much longer of course if you let it display the million rows in the console.

Comment: MonetDB uses all available physical memory - it ignores the memory limit, and when physical memory is exceeded, things get swapped. It's an in-memory DBMS. But I was hoping for an improvement at the query level rather than the execution plan.

Comment: You mean swapped by the OS? Is this occuring in your query? btw, if you want columnar storage, why not use clickhouse instead?

Comment: How many rows in the table? If the data is public, can I download it somewhere? I'd like to try something.

Comment: About 58 Million. A download & DB setup script is available [here](https://github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime-tools).

Comment: https://clickhouse.tech/benchmark/dbms/#[%22100000000%22,[%22ClickHouse%22,%22MonetDB%22],[%220%22,%221%22,%222%22]]

Comment: About swapping - If the implementation is efficient, no swapping should occur. The relevant input data It's only 5 columns x 58 Million x a few bytes per column. But again, it all depends on the implementation.

Comment: I've added some clickhouse test results, check it out!

Comment: At the link you posted, the queries do not regard the ontime dataset.

Comment: What does this mean? (I'm having trouble with the word "regard")

Comment: It means the queries are not about that dataset, they do not relate to it.

Comment: It's the dataset from the [link](https://github.com/eyalroz/usdt-ontime-tools) you posted.

Comment: bobflux, no, I don't think so. At the link there are fields like 'UserID', 'SearchPhrase' etc.

Comment: The github project you linked is "'usdt-ontime' benchmark tools". You mean it is not about the USDT-ontime dataset? Hmm...

Comment: My link is about the usdt-ontime dataset; your link doesn't seem to be.

Comment: No effort to explain, no help.

Answer (score 0):

In your query to create the temporary table, it's possible to do that in standard SQL without a sub-query, using a `HAVING` clause, e.g.:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dupe_keys AS (
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt, year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin 
    FROM ontime
    GROUP BY year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin
    HAVING cnt > 1
);
```

I don't know if that will speed up the temporary table creation, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: MonetDB doesn't recognize alaises in HAVING, unfortunately... [relevant bug page](https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues/3780). Regardless, though - how likely do you believe this is to improve perfoermance, in other DBMSes?

Comment: @einpoklum It might not help much as I believe the filtering in the HAVING clause is performed after the GROUP BY, so a sub-query is possibly as fast. Focusing on indices might be a better idea.

Comment: Actually, filtering by cnt can only happen after the GROUP BY, since you don't have the cnt before it's done. A super-smart DBMS could theoretically start filtering _while_ building the groups, but that's an unlikely optimization I would think.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this quite neatly with a window function:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin) cnt
    FROM ontime
) AS t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

This returns all rows which are duplicates. If you wanted instead to return only the extraneous rows, and not the first row from each group, use row-numbering:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_, month_, dayofmonth, uniquecarrier, flightnum, origin ORDER BY some_Other_Column) rn
    FROM ontime
) AS t
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Insert a column into the `ORDER BY` clause to decide which row orders first

Comment: I do want all the duplicates; the "first" is not automatically more valid than "later" lines. Will check this out soon, thanks.